# How to commit changes to the master branch in Gerrit?

Tags: git, branch, gerrit

I want to get whatever changes made in the feature branch into my master branch, then review the changes and then commit them. Could someone please share me the commands for GIT, to achieve this requirement?
I would also want to get it reviewed before performing the actual merge.
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I have a question. Do you want to review the result before the actual merge?

Comment: Yes I do want to review it before merging.

Comment: "get whatever changes made in the feature branch into my master branch" - what does it mean? Because then you wrote that after that you need to review them.

Comment: The below answer solved my query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understand your problem: review the result before the actual merge.

Please switch to your master branch. You use following command.

```
git merge --no-commit feature branch
```

Now, you can review the result and commit what you want.

You can return to previous state with

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: After this will I be able to review the change before merging?

Comment: Yes, you should try. If you have any problem, please contact me.